# Nested function doesn't read Combobox values from outer function when changed (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

In the following code, I'm facing the problem that after I choose a text from the second menu then change the color in the first menu, the background changes but the label background doesn't change, how can I fix this?

For example, if I first choose "red" and "Hi" then choose "yellow", "Hi"'s background will still be red.

Thank you in advance!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def show_color(self):
    def show_text(self):
        txt = menu2.get()
        if txt != "choose":
            text.configure(text=txt, background=cur_color)
            text.pack()

    menu2.pack()
    menu2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", show_text)

    cur_color = menu1.get()
    if cur_color != "choose":
        root.configure(bg=cur_color)

root = Tk()
root.geometry('900x500')
root.configure(bg='white')
root.resizable(False, False)

menu1 = ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly", values=["choose", "red", "green", "yellow"], width=55)
menu1.current(0)
menu1.pack()
menu1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", show_color)

menu2 = ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly", values=["choose", "Hi", "Hello", "Hey"], width=55)
menu2.current(0)

text = Label(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because when you just change the color, the nested function `show_text()` will not be executed and so the text background will not be updated.

Comment: @acw1668 I know but I am not able figure out a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since just changing color will not execute the nested function `show_text()` and so the text background will not be updated.

To fix it, bind the two comboboxes to same function which update the text based on the selections of both the comboboxes:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def show_text(event):
    cur_color = menu1.get()
    if cur_color != "choose":
        root.configure(bg=cur_color)
        text.configure(bg=cur_color)
        menu2.pack() # show the text selection combobox
    txt = menu2.get()
    if txt != "choose":
        text.configure(text=txt)
        text.pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('900x500')
root.configure(bg='white')
root.resizable(False, False)

menu1 = ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly", values=["choose", "red", "green", "yellow"], width=55)
menu1.current(0)
menu1.pack()
menu1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", show_text)

menu2 = ttk.Combobox(root, state="readonly", values=["choose", "Hi", "Hello", "Hey"], width=55)
menu2.current(0)
menu2.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", show_text)

text = Label(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In my actual code It's important for the second menu to appear after choosing a value from the first menu, so this solution isn't gonna work for me unfortunately, but thank you!

Comment: My solution will show the second menu after choosing a color.